# React Native Set up for WIndows

Tags: react-native

I am trying to set up a new React Native app for windows so I can start learning this technology. I went through the entire process of making sure my node was installed, JDK and android studio. When i run the "npx react-native run-android" command after setting up a project I just keep getting the error message:
error Failed to install the app. I then run "react-native doctor" and i get this:

```
Common
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ npm - Required to install NPM dependencies

Android
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 33.0.0
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
```

Errors:   1

I know that i have Android SDK because I installed it. I am so lost. Can anyone help?

Watched tons of videos and still havent managed to get the app to install.

Comment: The output says that you set `ANDROID_HOME` but it didn't find the SDK - does `ANDROID_HOME` point to the correct installation path of the SDK?

Comment: this is the path: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk, so i believe that it does